# Click an image and generate the same image using Javascript

Tags: javascript

The code below allows me to click an image and generate the same image below. I'm trying to figure out how the code below can go from handling one ID to handling two. I need to be able to have sets of pictures with separate ID's be able to be clicked and generate the same picture below. I cant seem to get it to work.

JS:

```
var imgCount = 5,
    i;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById('img' + i).addEventListener('click', setImg('img' + i), false);
}

function setImg(id) {
    return function () {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        if (imgCount) {
            imgCount--;
            img.src = document.getElementById(id).src;
            document.getElementById('footer').appendChild(img);
        };
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/1" />
<img id="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/2" />
<img id="img3" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/3" />
<img id="img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/4" />
<img id="img5" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/5" />
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Why not call that function over an array of id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need further `id`s to setup each image as clickable for cloning.

When an event handler is invoked, its `this` value will be the element that the event started from:

```
function setImg() {
    return function () {
        // ...
        img.src = this.src;
        // ...
    };
}
```

Since the element is provided to the handler for you, you can combine `setImg` and its embedded function:

```
document.getElementById('img' + i).addEventListener('click', setImg, false);
//                             note: no calling parenthesis  ^^^^^^

function setImg() {
    // ...
    img.src = this.src;
    // ...
}
```

To setup each new `img` to be clickable, you can bind `setImg` to them as well:

```
function setImg() {
    // ...
    img.src = this.src;
    img.addEventListener('click', setImg, false);
    // ...
}
```

---

```
<img id="img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/1" />
<img id="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/2" />
<img id="img3" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/3" />
<img id="img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/4" />
<img id="img5" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/5" />
<div id="footer"></div>
```

```
var imgCount = 5,
    i;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById('img' + i).addEventListener('click', setImg, false);
}

function setImg() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    if (imgCount) {
        imgCount--;
        img.src = this.src;
        img.addEventListener('click', setImg, false);
        document.getElementById('footer').appendChild(img);
    };
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdmmxrxp/

Answer (score 0):

Example below generates 2 sets of images, and clicking on either set adds the picture to the bottom of the page.

HTML:

```
<img id="set1Img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/1" />
<img id="set1Img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/2" />
<img id="set1Img3" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/3" />
<img id="set1Img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/4" />
<img id="set1Img5" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/5" />
<br />
<img id="set2Img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/6" />
<img id="set2Img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/7" />
<img id="set2Img3" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/8" />
<img id="set2Img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/9" />
<img id="set2Img5" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/10" />

<div id="footer"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var imgCount = 5,
    setCount = 2,
    i, j;

for (i = 1; i <= setCount; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= imgCount; j++) {
    document.getElementById('set' + i + 'Img' + j).addEventListener('click', setImg('set' + i + 'Img' + j), false);
  }
}

function setImg(id) {
    return function () {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        if (imgCount) {
            imgCount--;
            img.src = document.getElementById(id).src;
            document.getElementById('footer').appendChild(img);
        };
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b1q4n9pr/